# Macro (on button) to modify row where the cursor is

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, cursor

I want to be able to have a button on an Excel sheet,
place cursor on any row/column on the sheet,
click on button and the entire row defined by cursor row/column will modify (color fill and maybe move to another predefined sheet).

Can anybody offer me some pointers?

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you want to know how to bring a button into the sheet? Are you stuck in the "color-fill or moving the cell " part of the code? Where exactly are you in this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create this code with the help of contributions in this and in other similar forums. Since I'm a beginner with VBS this code sure looks complicated but it does what I needed.

I created 4 sheets and 4 buttons.
Each sheet includes 3 buttons.
Each button allows to cut and paste and color a row that has been previously selected by a mouse click on any cell in the row.
The 3 buttons refer to the 3 other sheets.
So the lines can move around between the 4 sheets and will be colored accordingly.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim strSheetName, strCellAddress As String
    strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    strCellAddress = ActiveCell.Address(False, False)

    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cut
    Sheets("Active").Select
    Range("A4").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Sheets(strSheetName).Select
    Range(strCellAddress).Select

    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is the answer, please do mark it as such :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ActiveCell.Address` in your macro, which returns the address of the currently selected cell or another attribute of `ActiveCell`.

Example to fill the entire row of the active cell with red when clicking the button `Button1`:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: I have assigned to a button and used successfully the  "ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color" . I struggle with moving the row to another sheet. Any pointer / sample would help. Also is there an command reference you would recommend to search for other commands ?

Comment: I should add that I now created 4 buttons with 4 different colors for status 1...4.  The idea now is that a row instantly moves to a specific sheet related to the rows' color at the time the color is assigned by button.

Comment: Please clarify better what you are trying to achieve. Rows cannot "move instantly" to a "specific" sheet "related to...". It is very fuzzy what you are saying.